# Is there a principle that makes it easier to understand how to form phrasal verbs?

Tags: sentence-construction, phrasal-verbs

I have seen a lot of websites and some books that explain what phrasal verbs are and then give mostly examples. But is there a general way to learn how to form a phrasal verb and especially to get the real meaning of the phrasal verb after adding, *up* / *with*… etc?

Comment: I think it's a misconception that one can "form" a phrasal verb.  Those have been formed for you by the centuries of language development, and you just need to learn to use them.  For instance, there is "hang out", "hang on", "hang about", but there isn't "hang to".

Comment: So there's no rule but just a list of phrasal verbs to study and learn?

Comment: A lot of phrasal verbs are idiomatic...

Comment: Is there a full list?

Comment: @Lukkio, I strongly doubt it, unless somebody created one as part of their research for a thesis or something.

Answer (score 3):

You won't find an easy way. You'll have to learn them as a part of a phrase, or as vocabulary, mostly.

However, here's a list of the most used particles to construct phrasal verbs.

---

***back*** = repeating or looking into the past.

> Could you **play back** the telephone message, please?
>   The tennis club **dates back** to the 19th century.

***down*** = record in writing or reducing.

> Could you **write** these dates **down**?
>   House prices have finally **gone down.**

***off*** = departing or ending.

> He quickly said goodbye and then **ran off** to catch the bus.
>    The two countries have **cut off** diplomatic relations with each other.

***on*** = continuing or attacking.

> She spent the whole time **going on** about her new partner.
>    Those bullies are always **picking on** Dave.

***out*** = disappearing or solving, searching.

> The forest fire finally **died out** after two days.
>    Can you **work out** the answer to this math question?

***over*** = visiting or considering, examining.

> We **popped over** to my mum's but she was out.
>    Let's **go over** the report before the meeting.

***up*** = approach or improve.

> He always **creeps up** on me. He just appears without making a noise.
>   I want to **brush up** on my computer skills this year.

Answer (score 0):

I am discovering that deeper, more profound answers require one to appeal to Linguistics. So search for or Google ["semantics of phrasal verbs"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22semantics+of+phrasal+verbs%22&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=cr&ei=ROKqVpORF4SMmQHN5bLgBA), to read some of the linguistics research papers, but which may presuppose knowledge of the branch of Linguistics called 'Semantics'; so maybe you can read an Introduction or two to Semantics first?

I was reading [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dummy_pronoun#Dissenting_views) which linked to the Wikipedia page for [Dwight Le Merton Bolinger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dwight_Bolinger) that introduces a book written by him that may aid you (but that I have not read; so do report back if it is bad):

> His 1971 book *The Phrasal Verb in English*, heretofore a subject of concern primarily to teachers of English as a foreign language, brought the need for a scientific treatment of [phrasal verbs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phrasal_verbs) to the attention of many linguists.